# Play Framework Request is null

Tags: playframework

I am new to Play Framework , i am uisng version 2.6 sample Project 
Inside the test folder i have written a Test Method as shown below

to test a external webservice http://techpaisa.com/supres/acc/

```
package it;

import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.containsString;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;
import static play.test.Helpers.GET;
import static play.test.Helpers.contentAsString;
import static play.test.Helpers.route;

import org.junit.Test;

import play.Application;
import play.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationBuilder;
import play.mvc.Http;
import play.mvc.Result;
import play.test.WithApplication;
import v1.post.PostData;
import v1.post.PostRepository;

public class IntegrationTest extends WithApplication {

    @Override
    protected Application provideApplication() {
        return new GuiceApplicationBuilder().build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testList() {
        PostRepository repository = app.injector().instanceOf(PostRepository.class);
        repository.create(new PostData("title", "body"));
        Http.RequestBuilder request = new Http.RequestBuilder().method(GET).uri("http://techpaisa.com/supres/acc/");
        System.out.println("THE REQIEST IS "+request.body().toString());
        Result result = route(app, request);
        System.out.println("THE RESULT IS "+result.status());
    }

}
```

This is the output i see

```
[success] Total time: 81 s, completed 10 Dec, 2017 9:47:23 PM
[play-java-rest-api-example] $ test
[info] Compiling 1 Java source to E:\minetest\play-java-rest-api-example\target\scala-2.12\test-classes ...
[info] Done compiling.
[info] Test run started
[info] Test it.IntegrationTest.testList started
[info] application - Creating Pool for datasource 'default'
[info] p.a.d.HikariCPConnectionPool - datasource [default] bound to JNDI as DefaultDS
[info] a.e.s.Slf4jLogger - Slf4jLogger started
THE REQIEST IS RequestBody of null
THE RESULT IS 404
[info] application - Shutting down connection pool.
[info] Test run finished: 0 failed, 0 ignored, 1 total, 9.37s
[info] Passed: Total 1, Failed 0, Errors 0, Passed 1
[success] Total time: 14 s, completed 10 Dec, 2017 9:48:14 PM
```

Could anybody please tell me why request is null

I even made it very simple , but still same error

```
@Test
    public void testBadRoute() {
        RequestBuilder request = Helpers.fakeRequest()
                .method(GET)
                .uri("http://techpaisa.com/supres/acc/");
        System.out.println("body"+request.body());
        Result result = route(app, request);
        System.out.println(result.status());
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your request is not `null`, but the body is: `request.body()`. In the case of a `GET` request it's normal to have an empty body.

Comment: ok , but why a 404 is coming , the website is http://techpaisa.com/ and one enter ACC and check console its a valid webservice

Comment: For testing an external website you should use the `WSClient`: see https://playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/JavaWS and https://playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/JavaTestingWebServiceClients

Here you are sending the request to your own play application

Comment: Oh God this is very confusing Framework , the WSClient is not getting compiled , i added libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  ws
)

Comment: Did you reload your sbt project ?